# Get the last value in a range of every nth cells

Tags: google-sheets, select

I'm looking for a formula that will give me the last value in a column, only taking the nth number of rows.

For example, I have data from row 7 to 93 and the data I am concerned with repeats every 3 rows. I would like to grab the last value in this range

I know I can get the nth rows in a range using FILTER(QUERY(E7:E,"Select * skipping 3") but unsure how to get the last value in that range

Comment: Use exact range E7:E93 and warp it in chooserows: =chooserows(QUERY(E7:E93,"Select * skipping 3"),-1)

Comment: I should have mentioned that not all cells are populated. So this returns nothing in my current case. I guess I need some kind of check that the cell isn't empty?

Comment: Paste some data sample and desired output.

Comment: Basically I have 30 rows, every 3 rows is split into a week, so I have 10 weeks worth of data. The 1st cell in every 3 is the data I wish to query, but some of the weeks are yet to be populated so appear blank.

Comment: So what do you want to do with blanks? This =CHOOSEROWS(tocol(QUERY(E7:E93,"Select * skipping 3"),1),-1)?

Comment: Ignore them. I just want the last populated value

Comment: Try formula in my last comment it will query for every 3rd row and will take last value from that array <>""

Comment: Excellent, that does exactly what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki for visibility, since the solution was provided by @user11222393 in the comments section.

The solution was to use the formula:

```
=CHOOSEROWS(tocol(QUERY(E7:E93,"Select * skipping 3"),1),-1)
```

This way it will skip the values every 3rd row, and using TOCOL with value `1` will help to transform the array and ignore the blanks, and using [CHOOSEROWS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13196659)  with the `-1` value will return the first row of the array.